# Certain hook_node_zyx APIs don't fire

Tags: drupal

I implemented hook_node_view but somehow this hook never get called. Then I tried some other hook_node_zyx APIs and found out that a few of them can get called (e.g., hook_node_insert) while most of them just don't fire. Does anyone have any idea what's the problem here? Thanks!

---

I researched on the web and there are some people saying 3rd party modules like CTools could cause situation like this, is this true? Here's a list of 3rd party modules I now installed:

- CTools
- Coder
- Devel
- Features
- Organic Groups
- Panels
- Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think ... but make sure that you cleared the cache after implementing the hook
and make sure that u are implementing the hooks correctly its better to show us the code that u wrote....dont forget to replace "hook" with ur module name

Comment: Clear the cache solved the problem. Before this I only knew that for menu related hooks I need to do this, didn't realize I need to do the same for node hooks. Thanks for the hint!